# Finding matching items in parallel lists

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cfset stateList = "Alabama,Alaska,Arizona, ..., Wyoming">
<cfset stateAbbrList = "AL,AK,AR, ..., WY">

<cfset stateAbbr = #ListGetAt("stateAbbrList",ListFind("stateList",form.state))#>
```

When form.state is Alabama, I would expect stateAbbrList to be AL. But instead, I get an error saying that ListGetAt is returning zero.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need take the quotes from around the variable names; if you use quotes, then you need to wrap in # signs.

```
<cfset stateAbbr = ListGetAt(stateAbbrList, ListFind(stateList, form.state)) />
```

OR

```
<cfset stateAbbr = ListGetAt("#stateAbbrList#", ListFind("#stateList#", form.state)) />
```

I will add that I don't think this is a good way of doing this; much better would be to use a `struct` or create a query.

```
<cfset stateStruct = { "AL" = "Alamaba", ..., "WY" = "Wyoming" } />
```